# Checkout issue - Continue button not working opencart in my store

Tags: opencart, checkout

I'm running a opencart store located at http://decoruscollection.com/

Continue button is not working when I use different shipping address.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What have you tried yet? Can you show us the bit of code that isn't working?

Comment: Is the country of the new address active, and does it have shipping set up to the zone ?

Answer (score 0):

You have validated `custom_field1` with message `"How did you hear about us required!"` But there is not any option to select this option in delivery details form. Its showing error in console but not in shipping address form. Put that field or remove validation for that field then it might work.